# Hazelcast not working with Spring security (no SessionRegistry bean found)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, hazelcast

I'am using Hazelcast 3.4 with Spring security 3.2.5. When I deploy the application and try to log in, the login is successful but an exception is thrown, resulting in an error page. Regardless of the error page I am logged in and my session is "alive". But after each login I always get the execption and as a result a land on the error page (which I have set up to appear in case of an unhandled exception).

My Hazelcast config in the web.xml:

```
     <filter>
    <filter-name>hazelcast-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.hazelcast.web.spring.SpringAwareWebFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>map-name</param-name>
        <param-value>at-sessions</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>sticky-session</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cookie-name</param-name>
        <param-value>hsessionId</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cookie-http-only</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>instance-name</param-name>
        <param-value>hazelcastInstance</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>shutdown-on-destroy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.hazelcast.web.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener> 


 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hazelcast-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

My hazelcast config in the Spring context xml:

```
<hz:hazelcast id="hazelcastInstance">
    <hz:config>
        <hz:instance-name>hazelcastInstance</hz:instance-name>
        <hz:group name="${hazelcast.group.name}" password="${hazelcast.group.password}"/>
        <hz:properties>
            <hz:property name="hazelcast.jmx">true</hz:property>
            <hz:property name="hazelcast.logging.type">slf4j</hz:property>
        </hz:properties>
        <hz:network port="${hazelcast.port}">
            <hz:join>
                <hz:multicast enabled="false"/>
                <hz:tcp-ip enabled="${hazelcast.tcp.ip.enabled}">
                    <hz:members>${hazelcast.tcp.ip.members}</hz:members>
                </hz:tcp-ip>
                <hz:aws enabled="${hazelcast.aws.enabled}"
                    access-key="${hazelcast.aws.access.key}"
                    secret-key="${hazelcast.aws.secret.key}"
                    region="${hazelcast.aws.region}"
                    tag-key="${hazelcast.aws.tag.key}"
                    tag-value="${hazelcast.aws.tag.value}"
                />
            </hz:join>
        </hz:network>
        <hz:map name="at-sessions"
            in-memory-format="${hazelcast.sessions.in.memory.format}"
            backup-count="${hazelcast.sessions.backup.count}"
            async-backup-count="${hazelcast.sessions.async.backup.count}"
            time-to-live-seconds="${hazelcast.sessions.ttl.seconds}"
            max-idle-seconds="${hazelcast.sessions.max.idle.seconds}"
            eviction-policy="LRU"
            max-size-policy="USED_HEAP_PERCENTAGE"
            max-size="${hazelcast.sessions.max.size}"
            eviction-percentage="${hazelcast.sessions.eviction.percentage}"
            merge-policy="${hazelcast.sessions.merge.policy}"
        />
    </hz:config>

</hz:hazelcast>
```

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry] is defined
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.common.general_002derror_jsp._jspService(general_002derror_jsp.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.57]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.57]
    ... 97 common frames omitted
```

Without Hazelcast the login is working completely fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same issue. The cause was I'm using the Spring Java Config for Spring Security using the DSL. Using the current Spring Security 4.0.1, the Configurer will create a SessionRegistry only on demand and (it looks like) not as a registered bean component.

I have fixed this with an explicit definition of the SessionRegistry.

```
    http
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .sessionFixation()
                .migrateSession()
                .maximumSessions(10)
                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()) // << this here!
                .and()
            .and()
```

and

```
@Bean
public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
    return new SessionRegistryImpl();
}
```

Unless Hazelcast's `WebFilter` is used, this is not required since Spring's `SessionManagementConfigurer` will ensure an instance of `SessionRegistry` will be created. But it cannot be found using the type `SessionRegistry`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all is Ok. You have configured all regarding the specifications.

[HazelCast Documentation](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.3/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html)

You don't have the most common errors in this configurations that is the use of **com.hazelcast.web.Webfilter**, instead of  **com.hazelcast.web.SpringAwareWebFilter** in your filter definition.

Furthermore you could check if your definition of the "sessionRegistry" bean is done in that way.

```
<beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry"/>
```

In any case, you could to take a look to the Hazelcast Code Samples in order to compare step by step all your configuration.

[HazelCast Code Samples](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/spring-security)

I hope it's useful to you.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you use xml configuration for spring context, make sure to define

```
<bean id="sessionRegistry"
  class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

in `spring-security.xml` (or whatever file you use to configure spring security context)